# cannot import proto file

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have spent hours trying to read blogs on how to use simple proto file in Golang. I generated the .pb.go files. All internet examples are littered with doing import from some random `"github...` urls for proto import. I am not able to find any example on how to import a simple proto file that exists in same dir as my .go file or diff directory. How do I use proto files from local file systems.

```
go build hello.go
hello.go:5:2: cannot find package "customer" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/customer (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/myhomedir/go/src/customer (from $GOPATH)
```

Contentes of `hello.go`in $SOME_DIR/customer

```
package main

import  (
    "fmt"
    pb "customer"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello test message\n")
}
```

Contents of `customer.proto`

```
syntax = "proto3";
package customer;


// The Customer service definition.
service Customer {
  // Get all Customers with filter - A server-to-client streaming RPC.
  rpc GetCustomers(CustomerFilter) returns (stream CustomerRequest) {}
  // Create a new Customer - A simple RPC
  rpc CreateCustomer (CustomerRequest) returns (CustomerResponse) {}
}

// Request message for creating a new customer
message CustomerRequest {
  int32 id = 1;  // Unique ID number for a Customer.
  string name = 2;
  string email = 3;
  string phone= 4;

  message Address {
    string street = 1;
    string city = 2;
    string state = 3;
    string zip = 4;
    bool isShippingAddress = 5;
  }

  repeated Address addresses = 5;
}

message CustomerResponse {
  int32 id = 1;
  bool success = 2;
}
message CustomerFilter {
  string keyword = 1;
}
```

Comment: Did you compile the .proto to a .go file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the Customer code in a directory and import it like you would a package

```
package main
import "$SOME_DIR/customer"
```

Comment: I did "import ./customer/customer" and it did not work

Comment: you have to include the directory of the current project. Your base directory is $GOROOT.

Comment: i am totally not getting what you mean. Can you be little more clear please

Comment: The base root that you are importing from is actually wherever your go/src/ directory is, which is your $GOPATH. Say your main package is hello (~/go/src/hello) and you have a customer package (~go/src/hello/customer).

Your import statement would be `import "hello/customer"`

Comment: I am still not getting it, Why is GOPATH relevant. Both my files(my hello.go and .proto file) are at /Users/mydir/Documents/golanglearn/shijuvar/proto/customer

Comment: To answer your question that why GOPATH relevant, please read the Golang documentation: https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Answer (score 1):

As some of the comments already mentioned, you have to import your `customer` file like any other go import - with its full url-like path. That is true even if your `main.go` is in the same directory as your dependency. 
There is a specific way in which everyone should manage go code dependencies and you can read about it here:

[How to write go code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

It does feel weird to follow a common standard of how to organize your workspace (at least to me it did when I first started with go) - but since you run into errors like yours if you don't follow them; just try to do it.

A pretty good place to start (after you've read 'how to write go code') is actually the error message you got. It will change if you change your import statement/directory structure and it will help you to specify the full path to your dependency in your `import ...` statement.